# C#, IronPython error: IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException - No module named requests

Tags: c#, python-requests, ironpython

Using VS 2019 I installed the nuget packages IronPython v2.7.11 and DynamicLanguageRuntime v1.3.0 and am trying to run a python script.  It ran fine until I added imports to the script:

```
import requests, time, socket
import random
```

Here’s the C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
    ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
    var searchPaths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
    // Path to where everything is installed for this Python enviroment
    searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\George\.conda\envs\spenv2");
    int url_id = 1701;
    string url = "https://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Health&geo_location_terms=Aliso+Viejo%2C+CA";
    ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
    engine.ExecuteFile(@"D:\Apps\Data Destinations\Scraping\ScrapeProjects\Job1.v4_For_IronPython_CSharp\ScrapeUrlPages.py", scope);
    dynamic testFunction = scope.GetVariable("scrape_all_pages_for_this_search");
    dynamic result = testFunction(url_id, url);
    Console.WriteLine(result);
}
```

I found a few posts regarding similar issues and the solution most of them was to add search paths.  Which I did:

```
searchPaths.Add(@"C:\Users\George\.conda\envs\spenv2");
```

This is where everything is installed for the Python environment, spendv2, is being used.
Any recommendations on what I need to do?
Thank  you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an incompatibility between IronPython and Python and the more I dug into this the more problems I found.

1. Not documented anywhere but I found someone from the IronPython crew who pointed out that IronPython 2.7.11 "Must" interact with Python 2.7.  Hmmm.  2.7 hit end-of-life a long time ago and you can't even download it from the Python site.
2. Not documented anywhere that I could find but IronPython 3.4 (just released) "Must" interact with Python 3.4, and yes, 3.4 hit end-of-life a long time ago and you can't even download it from the Python site.  I find this odd that a new release of something would be based on something obsolete.
3. I was able to get Python 2.7.n from nuget and after getting everything setup and configured, and set all the new paths, I was able to get c# to execute a python script via ironpython.  The script had the “import requests”  and it did run – where as before when attempting to execute the script I would get the error:

IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException - No module named requests
The script runs now – yippy  -  but – the python script gets an exception when calling the requests.get() method.  The exception is:

"not expecting type '<type 'bytes'>'"   object {string}

Evidently, from my searches, "not expecting type '<type 'bytes'>'" is a result of an incompatibility with the requests module and IronPython.  There are about 5 well known python modules that are not compatible with IronPython so when it get called it returns a blob of bytes.

In conclusion, to the best of my knowledge you cannot call python requests from c#
I hope this helps someone as it cost me several long painful days.

Comment: This is exactly what I hate about Python;  why are so many solutions out there to go back to an older version of Python?  Could they at least ATTEMPT backwards compatibility.... just a little?

Answer (score 0):

What I see is you're using the get for the searchpaths so you load the collection of strings but what is missing is the `engine.SetSearchPaths(searchPaths);` to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old post, but I found something that works for me that can help in future questions about this.

1. I installed `IronPython.StdLib` from the NuGet Package.
2. I downloaded the needed library (`Tkinter`) with my IDE (PyCharm) and then I added the folder to the `Lib` folder in my C# project.
3. I added

   ```
   var libs = new[] {@"{PATH OF YOUR PROJECT}\Lib"};
   engine.SetSearchPaths(libs);
   ```

And that works for me.

Comment: I do not understand line 2 at all.  Adding what folder?  and what do tkinter have to do with the 3 imports ?